# Parsing code in C brings extra characters

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing

I have the following string:

```
char *buffer = "begin\nvariables f,i,t\nf = 20\n:inicio\ni = i + 1\nprint i\nt = f - i\njnz t inicio\nend\n";
```

I want toparse every sentence out of there, and I developed an algorithm that does fine until I reach "jnz t inicio\n"

If I watch `(char *) buffer+65` I get `"jnz t inicio\nend\n"`, so, in order to get "jnz t inicio\n" out of there, I did the following:

```
void *output = malloc(13); // 13 being the length of jnz t inicio\n
memcpy(output,buffer+65,13); // to get the first 13 characters out of buffer+65
```

BUT, when I watch `(char *) buffer` I get `"jnz t inicio\n,t\n"`, I am getting that extra ",t\n" for some reason.

Any thoughts?

If you need any additional information, please ask. Thanks!

Comment: by "when I watch `(char *)buffer`", did you mean "when I watch `(char *)output`" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C strings must always be terminated with a `'\0'` character. So the buffer size needs to be 14 bytes, and you need to terminate the string after the copy.

```
void *output = malloc(14);
memcpy(output,buffer+65,13);
output[13] = '\0';
```